# ImageMagick - Eclipse

Tags: c++, eclipse, imagemagick

I am writing a small program using ImageMagick in Eclipse IDE.
My program compiles and runs fine but every call of display() (method which saws an image in a pop up window) has no effect. Through command line the same calls work fine so I assume that something is going wrong with Eclipse. I appreciate any help in advance.

Comment: How are you calling the [display](http://www.imagemagick.org/api/display.php) method? Are you working with `Magick++` or `MagickCore` API?

Comment: I call it this way: image.display() where image is an Image object. I work with Magick++.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `Magick::Image::display` method is expecting `DISPLAY` variable to be defined in the run-time environment. In Eclipse, under run/debug configuration, you should be able to set the environment value to whatever your X11 window manager's hostname. You can discover this value by echo-ing it out in command line.

```sh
#!/bin/sh
echo $DISPLAY
```

For your application, it may be wise to add error handling, or a user configuration option.

```cpp
#include <cstdlib>
// ...
const char * env_display = getenv("DISPLAY");
if ( env_display == NULL ) {
  // Error, or attempt to recover
}
```

You can also set the X11's hostname within the image object with `Magick::Image::x11Display`.

Comment: Ok I added DISPLAY variable in Eclipse and it works. Thank you very much.

Comment: Do you have any idea for this: 
"Magick: Unable to load font (-*-helvetica-medium-r-normal--12-*-*-*-*-*-iso8859-1) [Resource temporarily unavailable]."
Thanks again! :)

Comment: See [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20843054/how-to-write-text-with-angle-orientation-in-imagemagick/20844441#20844441), and when in doubt -- ask a new question.